# Select statement on non-existing columns not being caught by exception block

Tags: sql-server

I'm expecting an error here since X_TEST column doesn't exists.
But the error is not being caught by the exception block.

```
BEGIN TRY
   SELECT X_TEST FROM ACCOUNTS 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'There was an error! ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Why ? Is it because of the severity of the error ?

Comment: Non existent columns are compile time errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, TRY can only handle certain types of errors within its own scope. Now, you say you have a stored procedure that looks like this (after `non_existent_column` has been dropped):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.blat
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    SELECT non_existent_column FROM dbo.table_that_exists;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
  END CATCH
END
GO
```

If you simply do this...

```
EXEC dbo.blat;
```

...you will get hammered with a compilation error because the statement within that TRY's scope fails to parse:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fooblat, Line 5
Invalid column name 'non_existent_column'.
```

However you can catch this error at an outer scope (whether the procedure has `TRY/CATCH` or not):

```
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC dbo.fooblat;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT 'There was an error:';
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

Result (notice this is not an exception and the text is no longer red):

```
There was an error:
Invalid column name 'non_existent_column'.
```

You can also avoid this with dynamic SQL, but it seems like you've already shot that down, so this is the next best suggestion I can think of - capture the error at an outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

It is a syntax error to use a non-existing column. Your batch never even starts to execute.

Consider this code:

```
BEGIN TRY
   sdgedtju§$%&/()= 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'There was an error! ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

You would not expect it to even start, right? It does not compile. Using a non-existing column is just the same

Comment: I know what you mean. Yes, it would not compile now. But, what if the column used to exists and stored procedure created no problem. Then for some reason the column has been dropped. I would assume the catch block would take care ANY error in my TRY block. Am I missing something ?

Comment: When you change your schema your sproc will need to be recompiled. And then SQL Server will notice the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

This code would give you the behavior you were expecting to see...

```
BEGIN TRY
   exec('SELECT X_TEST FROM ACCOUNTS')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   PRINT 'There was an error! ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks Nunery. Two problems there. First, that forces me to enclose all my commands into a string (very inconvenient). Second, because they're in a string, SQL Server will not care whatever I put in there. Hence ignoring syntax and typo errors etc. It's like late binding with OLE.

Comment: Agreed.  Definitely don't want to do this in production:)  It was more to help illustrate how sql server works by giving an example.