# Catch is not working in my Stored Procedure - What is wrong with my code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, sqlclient

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspTryCatchTest
AS
BEGIN TRY
    -- Table does not exist; object name resolution
    -- error not caught.
    SELECT * FROM NonexistentTable;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

When i am execute this procedure i get object name resolution error...

How to fix it

Comment: Is this Sql Server?  If so, what version?

Comment: i'm using inbuilt sqlclient in vs2010

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219997/select-statement-on-non-existing-columns-not-being-caught-by-exception-block

Comment: The code block fails to *compile*. It's not surprising that code within that block is unable to catch such an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE uspTryCatchTest
AS
BEGIN TRY
    -- Table does not exist; object name resolution
    -- error not caught.
    EXEC('SELECT * FROM NonexistentTable')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

Execute the Select Query Using EXEC makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we're talking about MS SQL Server, TRY/CATCH blocks can only deal with certain types of errors. Your stored proc will cause a compile time error, whether or not you're using deferred name resolution. If you had a TRY/CATCH block encapsulating the call to this procedure, however, it would catch the error.

... interestingly, it looks like you've taken the code directly from the [reference page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) I was about to direct you to.

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
>   they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such 
>     as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because 
>     of deferred name resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use this to check whether the table exists

```
IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * 
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
         AND  TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'NOT Exists';
END
```